# Deploy sameersbn/docker-gitlab on AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gitlab, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to deploy [docker-gitlab](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab) on AWS ECS? Currently, I use docker-compose method to deploy on my own EC2 instance with a single docker engine setup manually. But now, I'm going to move them all to ECS service. So, if I use a Fargate/EC2 launch type on ECS, how to adjust its `docker-compose.yml` script to ECS way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to run it on ECS. But you need to use EC2 launch type.

I can see there are 3 containers in the docker-compose file. Redis, PostgreSQL and gitlab. I suggest you use `AWS Elasticache` for redis, and `RDS`/`RDS Aurora` for PostgreSQL and create an ECS Service for gitlab container.

You can map all the configurations for the gitlab from the docker compose file to a Task Definition manually and use it for launching ECS Service. Redis and Postgres endpoints and ports can be mentioned in the environment variables of task definition.

You would need to use an EFS mount for the data volume for Gitlab container. You can refer this [AWS document](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-ecs-and-docker-volume-drivers-amazon-ebs/) and [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/efs-volumes.html) on the same.